# What is this adjuster in the shifting cable?

Tags: shimano, shifter

In the shifting housing leading to my Shimano R7000 Front Derailleur sits an adjuster (see attached image). I could not find any documentation on the [Shimano Website](https://si.shimano.com/#/en/search/Keyword?name=R7000&name_web=). Does anybody know (1) what this is, and (2) when to use it?

[image: cylindric adjuster in shifting cable]

Comment: Looks like an adjuster to me.

Comment: Being on the cable of the front derailleur it has the same use as the barrel adjuster on the RD.

Comment: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/ultegra-6800/SM-CA70.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an inline barrel adjuster. By holding the end closest to the Shimano "O" and rotating the knurled end you can finely adjust the shift point of the front derailleur. If looking at it from the knurled end, counterclockwise rotation will make the adjuster longer.Clockwise rotation will make the adjuster shorter. This movement will increase or decrease cable tension.

Comment: Additionally, these are very useful when the front mech and the shfter both lack a fine adjustment barrel.

Comment: These things are used when the frame lacks cable housing stops with built-in barrels adjusters, perhaps because external full-length housing is used.